# Mysql update field with other field

Tags: php, mysql

It is possible to execute a query like this

```
update `project` set image='b/' `id_account` '.png'
```

?

```
id  int(10) NO  PRI     auto_increment      
id_account  varchar(100)    NO                          
image   varchar(100)    NO
```

I need to add value of field `id_account` into `image`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `+` operator to concatenate values in SQL:

```
UPDATE `project` SET `image` = 'b/' + `id_account` + '.png'
```